# How do I calculate a date by adding 30 calendar days, where end date must be business day?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm wondering if this is possible. I am creating a spreadsheet to track project due dates. Each project must be completed by the 30th calendar day, but must be turned in on a business day.

Currently, I am just adding 30 days to the start date but this means some due dates aren't always accurate. For example, if the 30th day is Saturday, April 2nd, then the real due date would be Friday April 1st.

Is there a way to construct a conditional such that the due date equals the 30th calendar day, unless that falls on a weekend / holiday, where it then falls on the next earliest business day?

I've been struggling to figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

For English settings in *Excel*, with a date in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(TEXT(A1+30,"DDDD")="Sunday",A1+28,IF(TEXT(A1+30,"DDDD")="Saturday",A1+29,A1+30))
```

[image]

This simple-minded approach only handles Saturdays and Sundays, not arbitrary holidays.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer more elegant way like using [WORKDAY.INTL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294972?hl=en)

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(A2+31,-1,1,E2:E)
```

**Explanation:** start date + 31 days (1 day more than maximum calendar days)

then subtract 1 working day - going to last previous working day

**Reason:** because this formula does know when are weekends (by using variables) and also knows to skip hollydays by a custom list.

here is an [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18UMteQoLkL5NKR49H-TZa3VwFGe-Uc_XlBqDTV15l_8/edit?usp=sharing) you can use

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Revised after comment:

Try this:

```
=(A4+30)+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A4+30),1,0,0,0,0,0,-1)
```

Your date, in A4, + 30 days, then add an amount of days until the next workday.  If A4 + 30 is a Saturday it will subtract 1 day, a Sunday will add 1.

Comment: Cool,  I think though the Sunday should be -2 not 1, but I like this one.